# Passing a C function pointer to emscripten callback

Tags: c, sdl-2, emscripten

I'm using SDL2 with emscripten for a little game. I'm trying to pass a function pointer to free some memory if the browser tab is reloaded or closed as follows:

```
emscripten_set_beforeunload_callback(0, on_before_onload);
```

The on_before_onload function signature is defined thusly:

```
char *on_before_onload(int eventType, const void *reserved, void *userData);
```

I'm getting this warning:

```
incompatible function pointer types passing 'char *(int, const void *, void *)' to parameter of type 'em_beforeunload_callback' (aka 'const char *(*)(int, const void *, void *)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
  emscripten_set_beforeunload_callback(0, on_before_onload);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm pretty new to C and am not fully grasping passing function pointers yet, apparently. I'm tried a bunch of different things to no avail.

It seems to call the function in Chrome, but not Safari even though the compiler complains.

How should I define the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before passing the pointer to function, you should declare the pointer to function like this:

`char * ( *on_before_onload_fptr )(int, void *, void *) = on_before_onload`

Comment: This totally worked with a couple tweaks to the types (using const etc)! Thank you!

Comment: This assignment is incorrect, and does not compile.  The `typedef` `on_before_onload_fptr `, once created should be used to _create_ the pointer `on_before_onload`.  The pointer is not _assigned_ to the declaration.

Comment: @ryyker, I ended up doing this, and it compiled and calls the correct pointer:  

`const char *on_before_onload(int eventType, const void *reserved, void *userData);`  

in main  

`const char *(*on_before_onload_fptr)(int, const void *, void *) = on_before_onload;  

  emscripten_set_beforeunload_callback(0, on_before_onload_fptr);  
`

Comment: @CocoaNub - Okay, I will remove my comment above.  Thanks for coming back to clarify.  But until the author of this post corrects the mistake, you should leave your comment as a clarification. :)

Comment: @ryyker, thanks for responding and for posting below as well!

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the prototype for `on_before_onload` is not correct.  [According to this,](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/html5.h.html#c.em_beforeunload_callback) it needs to be:

```
typedef const char *(*em_beforeunload_callback)(int eventType, const void *reserved, void *userData);
```

Where the parameters are defined as

```
    eventType (int) – The type of beforeunload event (EMSCRIPTEN_EVENT_BEFOREUNLOAD).

    reserved (const void*) – Reserved for future use; pass in 0.

    userData (void*) – The userData originally passed to the registration function.
```

- Return type `char *`, returns a string to be displayed to the user.

Use typedefed function pointer created above (`on_before_onload_fptr`) to create `on_before_onload`  in code location where it is in scope for use, perhaps `main()`:

```
em_beforeunload_callback on_before_onload;
```

Then, elsewhere in code the actual function is defined according The new type:

```
char *on_before_onload(int eventType, const void *reserved, void *userData)
{
    char *retBuf = NULL;
    //code to handle event here
    return NULL;
}
```